# Как добавить в List поля перебором?

Tags: c#

Сейчас я добавляю так:

```cs
myNodeList.Add(cor0);
myNodeList.Add(cor1);
myNodeList.Add(cor2);
myNodeList.Add(cor3);
myNodeList.Add(cor4);
myNodeList.Add(cor5);
myNodeList.Add(cor6);
myNodeList.Add(cor7);
myNodeList.Add(cor8);
myNodeList.Add(cor9);
myNodeList.Add(cor10);
myNodeList.Add(cor11);
myNodeList.Add(cor12);
myNodeList.Add(cor13);
myNodeList.Add(cor14);
myNodeList.Add(cor15);
```

и т.д.
Но есть ли красивое решение, как это сделать перебором, через выражение в имени поля? что-то такое:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 33333; i++)
{
    myNodeList.Add(cor${'i'});
}
```

То есть, в имени использовать параметр

Comment: есть: сделайте `cor` массивом.

Comment: Массив/список/словарь. Не множте имена переменных без нужды.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin
Нет возможности сделать cor массивом

Comment: "Нет возможности сделать cor массивом" - не бывает такого. Спросите нас, как это сделать.

Comment: А что такое `cor*`? Нутром чую контролы WinForms... В таком случае есть возможность.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не, это строки какие-то наверно

Comment: @rotabor `cor` это объект с набором поверхностей для представления геометрии и он не может быть массивом, в противном случае нельзя будет указать ссылку на объект во внешнем редакторе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myNodeList.AddRange(new string[] {cor0, cor1, ...})
```

Хоть какое-то облегчение :-)

Это шутка. А если серьёзно, то если переменные `cor*`- это поля класса, то получить к ним доступ по имени можно через рефлексию.

Это была ещё более злая шутка.

На самом деле АБ написал выше "есть: сделайте cor массивом". Мы-то поняли, что он хотел сказать. А он хотел сказать "есть: сделайте массив cor'ов"! Если тип `cor*` - `TCor`, а `X` - количество cor'ов, то

```
TCor[] cors = new TCor[X];
```

Это совершенно никак не изменит ни сами cor'ы, ни возможность доступа к ним из внешнего редактора, просто вместо `cor8`, например, нужно будет использовать `cors[8]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
  myNodeList.Add(cors[i]);
}
// хотя в данном случае
myNodeList.AddRange(cors);
```